# Insert a bibtex reference in a figure caption

Tags: floats, captions, citing

I want to add some citation references to a figure caption in a way that only the reference number appears in the caption **[Ref number]**, for example. I also want to know if it is applicable in table captions as well.

Comment: By "references in a figure caption", do you mean (a) citation call-outs or (b) cross-references to some item elsewhere in the document, say, a theorem or an equation? Please clarify.

Comment: i mean (a) reference the  source of the figure (Let's say it's coming from an article written by john .E)

Answer (score 4):

The command `\cite` and its close relatives, such as `\citet` and `\citep` provided by the `natbib` package are "fragile", in the LaTeX-specific sense of the word. If a `\cite` instruction needs to occur in the argument of a `\caption` instruction (and other directives with "moving arguments"), it needs to be `\protect`ed, again using LaTeX jargon.

Thus, write `\protect\cite{xyz}` instead of just `\cite{xyz}`. This applies irrespective of whether the `\caption` instruction occurs inside a `figure` or a `table` instruction.

Incidentally, the format of the citation call-out -- numeric, authoryear, or whatever -- is determined by the bibliography style and any citation management package you may be loading.