# How to make "\cite{RN8}" in "\listoftables"?

Tags: table-of-contents, citing

In one of my table captions, I inserted `\cite{RN8}` in the caption and the caption of the table showed normally. But when I saw the list of tables, I found that `\cite{RN8}` became the label `RN8`. How can I make the list of tables show the `\cite{}` command?

Comment: BiBLaTeX or BibTeX? If BibTeX, maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326467 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227833 helps.

Comment: Alternatively, use `\caption[caption version for list of tables]{normal caption}` to avoid the problem.

Comment: Going to bed now, sorry can't test in depth. Hope it helps. I think you have to provide more information and an MWE before you get better help.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Hello, it is BibTex. I check now. As I am a newbie, I don't know how to make an MWE. What I use is others made.

Comment: Take my code as an example. Also see the link in the top of my code: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407. Providing an MWE is essential to avoid missunderstandings. In addition, it helps you to understand the problem better.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner  I see wrongly as I use BiBLaTeX.

Comment: Going offline now. But your comments are confusing. Are you using bibtex or biblatex. Please provide an MWE based on my code and show your problem more clearly.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I use `biblatex`. I don't why when I tested your code, it is normal. When I tested my code, it can only show `key` name in my list of tables.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work in `BiBLaTeX`

[image]

```
% https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    FIGURE
    \caption{Caption \cite{key}.}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

---

### Update

It also works with `RN8` as a key. Maybe you have to clear the "cached files" (Overleaf).

[image]

```
% https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{RN8,
  author = {Author, RN.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    FIGURE
    \caption{Caption \cite{key, RN8}.}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I check your code and it is right. But why mine can't? Where determine the display of cited thing in the list of tables? If you tell me, I can modify that in my code.

Comment: Why chinging `key` to `RN` makes not show the cited reference?

Comment: @Y.zeng See update.

Comment: Thanks for your instruction. They are all right. Maybe my template has some limits to that function. My template can't do this. Thanks.

Comment: @Y.zeng That is why is essential to provide more information in your next question, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ for more information. Otherwise, it is just guessing and assuming things. Good luck!

Comment: What I am using is a big template that is written by some Chinese. The link: `https://github.com/whutug/whu-thesis/archive/refs/tags/v0.6d.zip`

Comment: @Y.zeng Seems like you can easily make an MWE using Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/wuhan-university-latex-undergraduate-thesis-template/kpystysgbgmr

Comment: I can make it easily. But the one I  make is different from the file: `https://github.com/whutug/whu-thesis/archive/refs/tags/v0.6d.zip`. In your template, it is all right. In the MWE I made, it will too. However, in the MWE of `https://github.com/whutug/whu-thesis/archive/refs/tags/v0.6d.zip`, it is not right. So can't make an MWE to show this problem.

Comment: Ah, ok. That seems different.

Comment: I feel it is `cls` file that makes something different.

Comment: I can understand that it is difficult for you.

Comment: Yes. I am just a newbie~

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work in `BiBTeX`.

[image]

```
% https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    FIGURE
    \caption{Caption \cite{key}.}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```